# Size of array with malloc function

Tags: arrays, pointers, malloc

I am learning C programming and this is my first course in programming. I am having some trouble with this snippet of code:

```
int* intArray;
intArray=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

I believe the number of elements in the array is 5 integers. However, what I don't really understand is the malloc function. Does it allocate enough memory for the addresses of 5 integers in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malloc returns a void pointer to the allocated space, or NULL if there is insufficient memory available. The parameter is the size, in bytes, to be allocated. So in the line `intArray = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));` you are requesting the allocation of memory *sufficient* for 5 ints (`sizeof(int)` gives the size of an int type). [(malloc)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Using malloc requests the allocation of memory sufficient for 5 new integers.

Comment: So it allocates 10 bytes of memory for the array: intArray?

Comment: @MatteoCiccozzi The size of an `int` varies depending on compiler. If `sizeof(int)` is 2 bytes, then yes it would allocate 10 bytes and return a pointer to the allocated space.

Comment: So essentially when I use the malloc it takes as input the amount of memory that I wish to be allocated, and the return is the address of the allocated memory?

Comment: @MatteoCiccozzi Pretty much exactly that. Just remember that the return is a pointer to the start of the allocated block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `malloc` allocates enough memory for 5 integers. It allocates what is passed into the function: `5*sizeof(int)`.  What might be confusing you is that `intArray` is a pointer allocated on the stack, which points to the memory address of the beginning of the malloc'ed memory.

If you want memory for addresses of 5 integers, you would do something like:

```
int** intArray;
intArray=(int**)malloc(5*sizeof(int*));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc` function allocates the number of bytes you request in the argument and returns the address in memory of the beginning of the block.  In this case you have requested a block of memory large enough to hold 5 integer values.

You cast it to an `int *` so the compiler will handle the address as containing integers when indexing and dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Malloc function call as you observe requires a value specifying number of bytes. From the documentation on malloc:

void* malloc (size_t size);

Allocate memory block. Allocates a block of **size bytes of memory**, returning a **pointer to the beginning of the block**.

The content of the newly allocated block of memory is not initialized, remaining with indeterminate values.

Hence, in your code snippet:

```
intArray=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

int size is 2 bytes. sizeof(int) returns 2. Hence 5 * sizeof(int) = 10. So, code resolves to intArray = (int*)malloc(10);